# Drawing a checkerboard iPython?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a checkboard. The following fails.  Where am I mistaken?

```
import turtle

side = 40

for i in range(8):
    turtle.backward(side)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(90)
for i in range(8):
    if (i % 2 == 0 and  i % 2 == 0) or (i % 2 != 0 and i % 2 != 0):
        turtle.begin_fill()
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.forward(side)
```

PS: read there is a similar question but the code is different.

Comment: You should say how you intend your code to draw a checkerboard.  You should also say how your code fails.  As originally posted, it had indent, spelling, and syntax errors.  I edited so it runs, but it is still woefully wrong.  I believe there should be some nesting of loops, in which case different loop variables are needed.  `i % 2 == 0 and  i % 2 == 0` is redundant.

Comment: Feel free to edit your code to better match your intention, but make sure it actually runs first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to draw a checkerboard would be to draw 9 parallel horizontal and vertical lines and then fill every other little square.  But tk and hence tkinter and turtle do not have floodfill functions like some drawing programs do.

I decided I needed more practice with turtle and wrote the following, which works, using a different plan: draw the outline of the board and then add 32 filled squares.

```
import turtle as t

def moveto(x, y):
    "Move turtle with pen up."
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()

def square(size):
    "Draw square of size, ending as started."
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)

def check(x, y, size):
    "Draw filled check at x, y of sides size."
    moveto(x, y)
    t.begin_fill()
    square(size)
    t.end_fill()


side = 40  # pixel size of squares
ll = -(4 * side)  # lower left of board

# turtle starts at 0,0 (center of screen) facing right)
# move to lower left corner of checkerboard
moveto(ll, ll)
# draw outline of board
square(8 * side)

# draw 32 filled squares
t.fillcolor('red')
for row in range(8):
    y = ll + row * side
    offset = row % 2
    for col in range(0 + offset, 8+offset, 2):
        x = ll + col * side
        check(x, y, side)
```

I developed this incrementally, starting with just the outer square.  I next added one filled square, then the rest.  I developed the little utility functions as I went, as I noticed repeat code.

You should still write your own code, using whatever plan you had.